# Can you use Chosen with dynamically created form elements?

Tags: forms, dynamic, jquery-chosen

I've created a simple form containing two selectbox elements. I also have a button which dynamically adds these selectboxes at the user's discretion. The selectbox options will be quite long, so I've applied the jQuery Chosen plugin to be more useful.

Everything works fine until a new element is dynamically added using jQuery clone. I am unable to select any options in my new element selectboxes, and they also carry the prior results.

In searching the forum, others have 'reset' Chosen after a selection, by calling: `$("#form_field").trigger("liszt:updated");` . I tried this as well, but it will just clear all the selections (which I don't want) and continue to freeze the dropdown action.

Anyone have experience with using Chosen (or any other autocomplete-type selectbox enhancement) with dynamic elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works - albeit without using the Chosen plugin.

I changed my dynamically created form elements by replacing the selectboxes with input fields tied to a basic jQueryUI autocomplete plugin. Here is a link to their implementation : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default.

The main difference is that the select "options" in this case, were listed as the source from which the box would look for autocomplete options. My list was 70 items long, so the initial setup took some time.

The jQuery text was generically as follows:

```
$("input#search").autocomplete({

    source: [item1, item2, item3, item 4, ... item5]);
```